# SharePoint 2013/Microsoft 365- How Get SAP web services data into sharepoint List

Tags: web-services, web, office-365-developer

I have a SAP web service like -http://orbex.orbexgroup.com:8010/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002P111AD1/sdef_url/VENDOR_MASTER?sap-client=196

what is the best way to achive this. Suggest me.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use BCS to pull data into SharePoint from SAP web service

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/102453/How-to-Integrate-SAP-Business-Data-Into-SharePoint